# jitpack use snapshot for branch on Android

Tags: android, github, jitpack

I wanna use branch m3 of repo github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial

I added in settings.gradle.kts

```
dependencyResolutionManagement { 
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
      ///added
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
    } }
```

and in module build.gradle

```
implementation ("com.github.leinardi:FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:m3-SNAPSHOT")
```

But got the error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.leinardi:FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:m3-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial-m3-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial-m3-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial-m3-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/m3-SNAPSHOT/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial-m3-SNAPSHOT.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

What i am done wrong?